# Create and Use custom environment variables in ruby via PLESK environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, plesk

I'm trying to host an app in plesk server. I created a custom variable as in the printscreen:
[image]

I want to access this variable in seed.rb file so that I could create a user with password through `rake db:seed`.

Is this the correct approach? Is there a better and safer way to create the admin user with sensitive data (password)? Please point a tutorial if you can.

**Edit:**
I'll provide some more info

I use this seeds.rb file:

`case Rails.env
  when "development"
    puts "Seeding: development mode!"
    ...
  when "production"
    puts "Seeding: production mode!"
    puts "ENV: #{ENV['admin_pass']}"
end
puts "Seeding finished!"`

and when i use the run rake task command that plesk provides i get this result:
[image: Rake db:seed result]

**EDIT #2**: Some solution!

when I provide the variable in task parameters It works!!! But what happens if I want to declare much more environment variables this way?
[image: some solution]

Comment: This is a fine approach. You can access it through the ENV hash.

Comment: Thanks @max, but when I test it with `puts ENV['admin_pass']` in seed.rb I get nothing.

Comment: did the web form have inputs for key and val? Or did you enter it as one string?

Comment: @maxpleaner: it had inputs

Comment: Theres also a lightweight, easy to use library for handling environment variables that I've enjoyed using: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

Comment: May be the rails environment is not correct. Can you try this command: `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed` and `puts ENV['admin_pass']` to print result

Comment: @APengue I'll give it a try but i still would like to know how to use the PLESK.

Comment: @taitrantuan I edited the post to provide more info. As you can see I use the commands you mentioned with no result

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your concern on solution 2. Another problem that solution is that you can't share environment variables for others application processes, such as: rails console or rails server.

Another solution is to use `figaro` to manage environment variables.

1. Add `figaro` to Gemfile
2. Create application.yml contains key-value configurations and upload to config folder.

------ config/application.yml ------

```
production:
  admin_pass: hello
```

Then try to run `rake db:seed` task again.

Comment: I tried that strategy already. what I don't like in this aproach is that password is hardcoded in a file. I think that figaro is a good solution on deployment and testing... not production

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature suggestion regarding this issue:

**Pass variables specifed in Ruby menu in field "Custom environment variables" to rake tasks**

> Currently, the option "Custom environment variables" in the menu "Ruby" on a domain is used only for passing environment variables to the application. But it's also required to pass environment variables to the rake tasks as well, and in the current implementation, it's necessary to specify necessary variables in the window "Run rake task" each time a rake tasks needs to be executed.
> Variables specifed in the option "Custom environment variables" should be passed to rake tasks as well, as similar options work this way in other products known for developers and used for hosting Ruby apps like Heroku and DigitalOcean.

You can vote for it [here](https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/43583589)